# Will the assignment of value in a Java Boolean object cause re-allocation in memory

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code

```
Boolean flag = new Boolean(false);
flag = true;
```

Will the second line (assignment) cause a recreation of the initial object (basically a call to new()) in the JVM? I am asking because I am using a Boolean object to synchronize multiple threads, and I am afraid that if a re-initialization takes places, the waiting threads will not see the change in value.

In my application, there are multiple threads that are given a reference to the previous Boolean object. Only one thread changes the objects value to true, and the rest wait until the object's value becomes true. So, if T1 is the thread that changes the value, its code is like:

```
synchronized(flag) {
    flag = true;
    flag.notifyAll();
}
```

and the rest of the threads (T2) will have code like:

```
synchronized(flag) {
    while(flag == false)
        wait();
    if(flag == true) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Therefore, the question is that after the assignment of true to flag, will the other threads (T2) still have access to the original object?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Ok, your last paragraph hints at your underlying problem. Rather than focussing on some specific question about your proposed solution, can you tell us more about your problem and we can help you find a good solution. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You can use `volatile` to make sure the reference is updated for threads.

Comment: "I am using a Boolean object to synchronize multiple threads". By this, do you mean that you are obtaining a lock on the Boolean object or just using the boolean object as a flag?

Comment: For boolean literals being boxed, the resulting value is always either `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`, depending on the literal.

Comment: @bot I am using the Boolean object as a flag.

Comment: @m0skit0 I do not believe volatile would help, since the reference of the Boolean object is given to the threads, before the update in the object's value occurs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you mean by "being boxed" ?

Comment: `boolean` to `Boolean`

Comment: @nick.katsip Never heard about that being a problem. `volatile` is a declaration modifier.

Comment: @m0skit0 Well, the volatile keyword guarantees that the changes in the object will take place directly in memory (and in one specific address). However, if the assignment of a new value in the Boolean object creates a new Object somewhere else in-memory, volatile will not really help me, right? (since the object would point to another location in memory).

Comment: @nick.katsip: don’t think in terms of memory locations. `synchronized` works on an *object instance* and all of its guarantees only apply if the threads are synchronizing *on the same object instance*. That’s why applying `synchronized` on a mutable variable is wrong in 99.9999% of all cases.

Comment: @nick.katsip In my understanding of `volatile`, your sentence doesn't make much sense... The reference is guaranteed to be updated, because the reference was declared as volatile.

Comment: You can not change the value of a `Boolean` _object_.  You are talking about changing the value of a `Boolean` _variable_.  (See @Holger 's answer for the long version.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignment `flag = false` is a [*boxing conversion*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). It will get compiled as [`flag=Boolean.valueOf(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean)) which will end up returning the constant [`Boolean.FALSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#FALSE).

So the answer is, it will not create a new object but it will change the variable `flag` as it assigns an instance distinct from your previous result of `new Boolean(false)`.

It’s not quite clear what you are actually doing but in general, synchronizing on a mutable variable is broken design.

---

The problem is that you are mixing the value that makes up your condition and the object to synchronize on. The simplest implementation of your updated intention is to use a simple `boolean` flag and synchronize on the instance that contains the flag:

```
class WithFlag {
  private boolean flag;

  public synchronized void setToTrue() {
    if(!flag) {
      flag=true;
      notifyAll();
    }
  }
  public synchronized void waitForTrue() throws InterruptedException {
    while(!flag) wait();
  }
}
```

Note that declaring an instance method `synchronized` is similar to wrap its code with `synchronized(this) { … }`

Comment: well, what would be an alternative better design for synchronizing threads? any suggestions?

Comment: As said, we don’t know what you are doing. We can’t tell you how to do it when we don’t know what “it” is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments on this post. Helped me realize better what happens with boxing in Java.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a boolean to synchronize threads, you should consider using `AtomicBoolean`, which is specifically designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have already explained that when you say `flag=false`, it is a boxing conversion which will return the constant `Boolean.FALSE`. One important point that the other answers have covered but not emphasized on is that when you obtain a lock on two Boolean objects that were assigned the same value through a boxing conversion, it is as good as obtaining a lock on one Boolean object.

My answer attempts to give an example to explain this. Consider the following code that creates two threads that obtain a lock on a Boolean.

```
public class BooleanTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanTest test = new BooleanTest();
        test.booleanTest();

    }

    private void booleanTest() {
        BooleanLockTester booleanLock1 = new BooleanLockTester();
        booleanLock1.setBooleanLock(true);
        BooleanLockTester booleanLock2 = new BooleanLockTester();
        booleanLock2.setBooleanLock(true);
        BooleanLocker booleanLocker1 = new BooleanLocker(booleanLock1);
        BooleanLocker booleanLocker2 = new BooleanLocker(booleanLock2);

        Thread threadOne = new Thread(booleanLocker1);
        Thread threadTwo = new Thread(booleanLocker2);

        threadOne.start();
        threadTwo.start();
    }

    private class BooleanLocker implements Runnable {

        private BooleanLockTester booleanLockObj;

        public BooleanLocker(BooleanLockTester booleanLockObj) {
            this.booleanLockObj = booleanLockObj;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            booleanLockObj.testLockOnBoolean();
        }

    }

    private class BooleanLockTester {

        private Boolean booleanLock = false;

        public synchronized void testLockOnBoolean() {
            synchronized (booleanLock) {
                for (int i = 0; i<1000000000; ++i) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
        }

        public void setBooleanLock(Boolean booleanLock) {
            this.booleanLock = booleanLock;
        }

    }
}
```

In the above example, the two threads will never be able to enter the for loop together. When you run the program, you will see that the thread that starts first will start printing on the console and only when it is finished, the next thread will start printing to the console.

Let's make a small change in the above code :
Change the following line in the code :

```
booleanLock2.setBooleanLock(true);
```

To this :

```
booleanLock2.setBooleanLock(false);
```

You will now see that the threads stop behaving and print to the console in a random order. This is because the threads now obtain a lock on two different objects.

Comment: Taking “when you obtain a lock on two Boolean objects with the same value, it is as good as obtaining a lock on one Boolean object” literally, it is a wrong statement. Only synchronization *on the same instance* work. It is a side-effect of the boxing conversion returning only one of two instances that make your code work. If you are using the constructor of `Boolean` to create instances (like in the question), this will not work. Locking on two distinct instances created via `Boolean(true)` will *not* work, despite having the same value.

Comment: By the way, I don’t get why are you spreading your example over three classes. That distracts the reader from the important parts.

Comment: @Holger I agree. That sentence is wrong. I meant to say something else. Edited my answer. And I am not used to coding everything in one class. Feel free to post your own example.

Comment: @bot Thank you very much for the info. Your comments helped me clarify things better in my brain.